# Refreshing Drawable Background outside of Class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, drawable

I've been working on modifying code for a game to include a feature where a user can select their own image off the phone to use as a background. There are two classes in the current file I'm working with called `GameActivity` and `GameView`. I have an activity in `GameActivity` which opens the phone's gallery and lets a user select an image once a button is pressed on screen. The location of the image is then suppose to be passed as a path to the `Drawable` object. The `setBackgroundDrawable()` function is part of the `View` class (which `GameView` extends) so I can't directly access it in the Activity Result function for the image selection. The original `setBackgroundDrawable()` is part of `GameView's` constructor.

Here is the constructor:

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    requestFocus();


    mDrawableBg = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lib_bg);        //Mod 1

    setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawableBg);

    mBmpPlayer1 = getResBitmap(R.drawable.lib_cross);
    mBmpPlayer2 = getResBitmap(R.drawable.lib_circle);

    if (mBmpPlayer1 != null) {
        mSrcRect.set(0, 0, mBmpPlayer1.getWidth() -1, mBmpPlayer1.getHeight() - 1);
    }

    mBmpPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    mLinePaint = new Paint();
    mLinePaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mLinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    mWinPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mWinPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
    mWinPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    mWinPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    for (int i = 0; i < mData.length; i++) {
        mData[i] = State.EMPTY;
    }

    if (isInEditMode()) {
        // In edit mode (e.g. in the Eclipse ADT graphical layout editor)
        // we'll use some random data to display the state.
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mData.length; i++) {
            mData[i] = State.fromInt(rnd.nextInt(3));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can adjust the background from `GameActivity` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a set method inside the GameActivity class that will set mDrawableBg.

```
public void setBackground(URL url){
GameViewClassInstance.mDrawableBg = url
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, just setting mDrawableBg doesn't make anything happen. The setBackgroundDrawable() function would still need to be called, unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: You can access variables and functions of another class by ClassInstanceName.VariableOrFunction.